# Detect if app is running in development mode or not

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

does anyone know a good way to, in code, detect if the app is running in development mode or production mode?

Comment: At compilation time or at run time ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends entirely on how you choose between development and production mode. Xcode 4, by default, sets the `DEBUG` flag when you are running the app under debug. You can create conditional code like so:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  NSLog(@"Only log when in debug");
#endif
```